# JTextArea getColumns, getRows returning 0

Tags: java, swing

I have a `JTextArea` I want to display a specific array of lines of text based on the number of columns and rows; but `getColumns` and `getRows` are returning zero. The following should give an idea of what I am trying to accomplish:

```
public class Frame extends JFrame implements ComponentListener {
    ...
    this.textArea = new JTextArea();
    this.textArea.setFocusable(false);
    this.textArea.setFont(new Font(Font.MONOSPACED, Font.BOLD, 20));
    this.add(textArea, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    this.editor = new Editor(new File("test"));
    this.textArea.addComponentListener(this);
    ...
    @Override
    public void componentResized(ComponentEvent ce) {
        this.editor.setHeight(this.textArea.getRows());
        this.editor.setWidth(this.textArea.getColumns());
        drawText();
    }
```

Why are `getRows` and `getColumns` returning zero?

Comment: @trashgod I am trying to get the available columns and rows, not set them.

Comment: The row/columns properties are hunts used by the text area to determine its preferred size, they don't update

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this constructor

```
javax.swing.JTextArea.JTextArea(int rows, int columns)
```

EDIT:

try this:

```
this.editor.setHeight(this.textArea.getHeight());
this.editor.setWidth(this.textArea.getWidth());
```

Comment: Can you put *why* I should use this particular constructor? Not everyone peruses the comments of a question.

Comment: @MotokoKusanagi Did you try this another way that I've suggested above?